# Is changing the system hostname on a server with a running MySQL / MariaDB service harmful?

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, hostname, mariadb

I want to change the hostname of a running CentOS 7 server which is running MySQL (`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.33-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`). Although I can't find any sources specifically referencing this, the following question just to be sure:

Is changing the system hostname on a server with a running database service harmful? Is it better to shut down the service, then change the hostname, and then start it again?